# Modifying default connection string to add users VS2013 project - The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've created a new C# MVC project in VS2013 and am trying to use their automatically generated user creation function.

It seems in the IdentityModel.cs file, there is a method called ApplicationDbContext as shown below with the "DefaultConnection" string.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Now this seems like its using VS's in built database as shown in the Web.Config file

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AI-20150321012806.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AI-20150321012806;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm wanting to use my own database connection string instead while using the in built user creation functions (as the in built user creation seems to have all the fields i need for user creation, and handles password hashing and such), but I can't seem to get the user creation to work when i change the "DefaultConnection" string to my own connection string as defined in the Web.Config file.

```
    <add name="AIEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AIEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.AIEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.AIEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PC;initial catalog=AI;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Every time when i try to create a new user, i get the error message:

**The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.**

**Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.**

**Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.**

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
```

What is needed to get the user creation control to work exactly how it would do while changing the connection string?

Comment: How is it that your data source is equal to PC ? Just curious, dont think this is the problem. Just never seen that before

Comment: PC is just the name of my SQL server i've installed on my machine, so when i use SSMS, i connect to that server name.

Comment: Dont you have to specify the type first though .. like `SQL2012\INSTANCENAME` .

Comment: I'm not so sure, but that's automatically generated for me when i use the "Add New Item ==> ADO.NET Entity Data Model" using VS2013. I've used my databases like this with no problem (although all those times I never used pre made database code as im experiencing above). I'll try adding SQL2012 in front of my server name and see if that fixes it, maybe this particular template doesn't like the auto generated connection string names. - Just tried adding "SQL2012" in front of the data source, still same error.

Comment: yeah i dont think this is the problem. You can test it with `(local)\PC` which automatically finds the local instance. Just curious is all . cheers

Comment: Yes your connection string' look a bit weird. Also, make sure your AccountController is using ApplicationDbContext

Comment: @gerdi unfortunately that doesn't fix it, thanks for your help though

Comment: Think you can edit your connection string as below: <add name="AIEntities" connectionString="Data Source=server; Initial Catalog=db_name; User ID=user_id; Password=password; Connect Timeout=60;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Thanks Hasta Pasta, I've figured out something similar to yours just a few minutes ago! I've written what i did to get it to work (similar to yours, and changed the user id & password to be "integrated security" and added an initial catalog). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this is very interesting, I came across this article:
http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context which seems to describe the problem i'm getting, although their "answer" doesn't work for me (and also for the others who have also commented that it doesn't work for them either).

However after reading "Matt"s comment:

*Matt*
*February 11, 2014 at 03:31*
*I was having this same problem, and I recall having a similar problem working with SimpleMembership in MVC4.*

*I’m doing database first development, so I have an EDMX file. Turns out, ASP.NET Identity does not like the connection string that is created when you generate your .edmx model file. If you are using a. EDM connection string in :base(“EDMConnString”) you will most likely have this problem.*

*I fixed this by creating a standard connection string that pointed to the database where the ASP.NET Identity tables are (in my case the same database), used that connection string in :base, and it worked.*

I tried doing the same thing and created a new ConnectionString as follows (basically removed everything that got auto generated when i added a new model):

```
<add name="AI2" connectionString="data source=PC;integrated security=True;initial catalog=AI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And under the IdentityModels.cs file, set my connection string to AI2:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
: base("AI2", throwIfV1Schema: false)
   {
   }
```

And this seems to have solved my problems, it's doing exactly what the template code was doing on its local DB onto my own DB.

Comment: Yep I had reached the same conclusion and had commented in the above post. Glad it worked..

Answer (score 1):

Well the name of your connection is AIEntities before it was DefaultConnection. In your ApplicationDbContext constructor rename your DefaultConnection to AIEntities

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("AIEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
   {
   }

   public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
  {
     return new ApplicationDbContext();
  }
}
```

The `ApplicationDBContext` then passes that string to connect

Comment: Also check your IdentityDbContext. It should point to AIEntities. You are getting this error because it does not know what the DefaultConnection is as you have changed the connection string

Comment: Is your first answer saying i should do this?

public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("AIEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

If so, I've already changed the "DefaultConnection" to say "AIEntities" (the name of the new model's connection string in Web.config created by ADO.NET entity data model), but that's whats causing that issue to come up in the first place.

Comment: Yes. And also because your connection string has changed I was suggesting you to figure out where else it was being used. As I see you have more than one context ApplicationDbContext and IdentityDbContext

Comment: Can you post your IdentityDbContext as well?

Comment: So this is the file generated by VS2013 when a project was created. This is what shows up when i search for IdentityDbContext: http://pastebin.com/Ae68rVuv.